# Php not writing newlines from javascript textarea

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create a .txt file on my server when a user submits a form. However any newlines from the comment textarea is not reflected in the resulting .txt file.

Here's my code:

Javascript

```
function sendInfo(){
var name = document.getElementById("scenarioName").value;
var author = document.getElementById("author").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var comments = document.getElementById("comments").value;

var urlString = "get_info.php?name="+name+"&author="+author+"&email="+email+"&comments="+comments;     

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("successParagraph").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET",urlString,true);
xmlhttp.send();}
```

PHP

```
$content = $_GET['name']."\r\n".$_GET['author']."\r\n".$_GET['email']."\r\n".$_GET['comments'];
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $fp = fopen("files/".$_GET['name'].".txt","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

So if the comment was:

"foo

bar"

Then in the textfile this would be a single line, reading "foobar"

Comment: don't use get for such information. use post and it will work

Comment: Changed the javascript to xmlhttp.open("POST",urlString,true);, and the PHP $_GET's to $_REQUEST, but that didn't change it. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Right, I don't know why or how, but I've worked a solution to this.
The issue seemed to be the way the php file was writing the content, it appears to ignore newlines.
So I split the comments by the newline character, and used a foreach loop to write each line into the file. As so:

```
$content = $_POST['name']."\r\n".$_POST['author']."\r\n".$_POST['email']."\r\n";

$comments = split("\n",$_POST['comments']);

if(isset($_POST['name'])){
$fp = fopen("fine-uploader/files/".$_POST['name'].".txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
foreach($comments as $c){
    fwrite($fp,$c);
    fwrite($fp,"\r\n");
}
fclose($fp);
}
```